# Grails: Carry forward params on hyperlink is clicked

Tags: grails, redirect, controller

How to carry forward the parameters when hyperlink is clicked?

Here is my `gsp` code:

```
<g:link class="grid_link" controller="user" action="delete" id="${userInstance.id}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure, want to delete?')}');">Delete</g:link>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
def delete() {
    try {
        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)

        //deleting the user
        //successful.

        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Deleted Exception---->>" + e.getMessage())
    }
}
```

redirect is missing with `params`. I wanted to carry forward `params` on `redirect`.

The URL before I clicked on 'delete' hyperlink looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/message/list?offset=10&max=100
```

After 'delete' hyperlink is clicked, the url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/message/list/11
```

How do I carry forward the parameter when hyperlink is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to the redirected URL, you will realize that `params` are carry forwarded correctly. `11` the only `params` you have in your delete action and that is forwarded to list action (`.../list/11`) after successful delete.

The issue is that you are not passing `max` and `offset` with delete call. Change your link as

```
<g:link params="${params}" class="grid_link" controller="user" action="delete" id="${userInstance.id}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure, want to delete?')}');">Delete</g:link>
```